# Evaluate cumulative cost

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Example 10.2**
>
> A wind energy conversion system of capacity $1$ MW is installed at a cost of Rs $45\,000\,000$ and connected to the electricity grid. It works at an annual capacity factor of $20$ per cent. Assume:
>
> 1. The Electricity Board purchases the electrical energy at the rate of Rs $3.00$ per kWh and that this price increases by $5$ per cent every year.
> 2. $85$ per cent of the initial cost of Rs $45\,000\,000$ is financed through a loan borrowed at the rate of $5$ per cent to be repaid in equal instalments in $5$ years.
> 3. The rate of depreciation is $80$ per cent in the first year and the remaining $20$ per cent in the second year. The corporate tax rate is $31$ per cent.
> 4. No tax saving is allowed on the interest component of the loan repayment.
> 5. The annual operation and maintenance costs in the first year are $2$ per cent of the total cost of the system. This expense increases at the rate of $6$ per cent every year.

the problem I got is, how they evaluated the sale of electricity and tax savings. the answer is available [in this book page no 309](http://books.google.com.bd/books?id=O8IMS-jq6skC&q=present%20worth%20clculations#v=snippet&q=present%20worth%20clculations&f=false)